# Write a c program to implement the following Uinix|Linux command (use fork,pipe and exec system call) ls -l|wc -l

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I have question in my assignment
**Write a c program to implement the following Uinix|Linux
command (use fork,pipe and exec system call)
ls -l|wc -l**

The following solution is correct?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int fd[2],dupFd;
    char *filename1 ="ls";
    char *filename2 ="wc";
    char *arg1 = "-l";
    pipe(fd);
    if(!fork())// return 0 for child process and 1 for parent process
    {
        close(1); // 1 for closing stdout
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        execlp(filename1,filename1,arg1,NULL);
    }else
    {
        close(0);
        dup(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp(filename2,filename2,arg1,NULL);
    } 
}
```

Output is

```
(base) amol@amol-Ideapad-320:~/AOS$ ./a.out
total 140
drwxrwxr-x 2 amol amol  4096 May 28 16:19 adir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amol amol 11962 May 29 13:59 AOSSolution2022.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amol amol 16912 May 29 14:00 a.out
drwxrwxr-x 3 amol amol  4096 May 28 17:34 kdir
```

I need to understand what is above program is actually doing....!

Comment: Your program is not performing `ls -l | wc -l`, since the later should just print the number of lines produced by `ls -l`.